# How to implement deleteMax() in MinHeap taking log(n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm implementing `MinHeap` I know how to implement `deleteMax()` but it takes `O(n)` time 
But I need `O(log(n))` algorithm..

I searched and didn't find a way to do this, if it exists
Is there any way that I can `deleteMax()` in `O(log(n))` times?

Comment: Sounds like some homework :p, what have you tried first?

Comment: I already tried first...and not a homework. I just heard that it can that's why i posted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a [Min-max heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), which does `deleteMin()` and `deleteMax()` in O(log n) time.

That's the only O(log n) way I know of to do what you want. The Min-max heap has the same asymptotic bounds as a Min-heap or Max-heap, but its real world running time will be somewhat longer.

Comment: I made a MimHeap and MaxHeap

Comment: My goal is making a Min-Max Heap so in MinMaxHeap when i implement deleteMax()  i coudnt find the way deleting max value at each heap at the same time.

Comment: @user2981593: A Min-Max Heap is not a data structure that contains two separate heaps. It is a single heap that is structured in a particular way. The original paper: [Min-Max Heaps and Generalized Priority Queues](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf).